# vuejs Editing conditions of data from

Tags: vue.js

I'm making a table listing with vuejs. My data from the database is as above. I'm transferring the data that comes with axios to "data.userList". What I want to do is; if "transaction_type" I want to edit. If I try to convert the data from the table, it will be too long. what should i do for him?
Examle:
I want to make the conditions I have written more regular. Considering that there are thousands of "transaction_types" like this, it's a lot of work. how can i edit this?

```
"transaction_type" I want to rename it according to the type of incoming data.
```

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        userList: [{
                id: 1,
                name: "Prem",
                age: 18,
                status: "close",
                gender: "male",
                transaction_type: 'initial_account_balance'
            },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Chandu",
                    status: "close",
                    age: 20,
                    gender: "female",
                    transaction_type: 'contact_debit'
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: "Jong",
                    status: "open",
                    age: 21,
                    gender: "female",
                    transaction_type: 'contact_credit'
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: "Steew",
                    status: "open",
                    age: 33,
                    gender: "male",
                    transaction_type: 'account_debit'
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    name: "Abdollah",
                    status: "open",
                    age: 26,
                    gender: "female",
                    transaction_type: 'account_credit'
                },
                {
                    id: 6,
                    name: "Jerry",
                    status: "open",
                    age: 35,
                    gender: "male",
                    transaction_type: 'account_debit'
                }
            ]
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(user, i) in userList" class="position-relative">
            <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.status }}</td>
            <td>
            <p v-if="user.transaction_type ==='initial_account_balance'">Opening Balance</p>
            <p v-if="user.transaction_type ==='contact_debit'">Customer Advance</p>
            <p v-if="user.transaction_type ==='contact_credit'">Customer</p>
            <p v-if="user.transaction_type ==='account_debit'">Customer sales</p>
            <p v-if="user.transaction_type ==='account_credit'">Customer Buy</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ user.gender }}
                <!-- This can be placed in any of the <td>'s -->
                <a class="stretched-link" :href="`#${user.id}`"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to give the user a select based on transaction types found in the data. filter the large data set with the user's selection...

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    xactionType: '',
    userList: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Prem",
        age: 18,
        status: "close",
        gender: "male",
        transaction_type: 'initial_account_balance'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Chandu",
        status: "close",
        age: 20,
        gender: "female",
        transaction_type: 'contact_debit'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Jong",
        status: "open",
        age: 21,
        gender: "female",
        transaction_type: 'contact_credit'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Steew",
        status: "open",
        age: 33,
        gender: "male",
        transaction_type: 'account_debit'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "Abdollah",
        status: "open",
        age: 26,
        gender: "female",
        transaction_type: 'account_credit'
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: "Jerry",
        status: "open",
        age: 35,
        gender: "male",
        transaction_type: 'account_debit'
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    xactionTypes() {
      return this.userList.map(e => e.transaction_type);
    },
    filteredData() {
      return this.xactionType ? this.userList.filter(e => e.transaction_type === this.xactionType) : this.userList;
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label for="xactionType">Select transaction type:</label>
    <select id="xactionType" v-model="xactionType">
      <option v-for="(type, i) in xactionTypes" :key="i" :value="type">{{type}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(user, i) in filteredData" class="position-relative">
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.status }}</td>
        <td>
          <p v-if="user.transaction_type ==='initial_account_balance'">Opening Balance</p>
          <p v-if="user.transaction_type ==='contact_debit'">Customer Advance</p>
          <p v-if="user.transaction_type ==='contact_credit'">Customer</p>
          <p v-if="user.transaction_type ==='account_debit'">Customer sales</p>
          <p v-if="user.transaction_type ==='account_credit'">Customer Buy</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ user.gender }}
          <!-- This can be placed in any of the <td>'s -->
          <a class="stretched-link" :href="`#${user.id}`"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You misunderstood me. I say "v-ifs".

Comment: "transaction_type" I want to rename it according to the type of incoming data.